# Unix hostid and Windows

Tags: windows, unix

Is there a Windows equivalent to the unix hostid?

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hostid.htm

Comment: Since `hostid` doesn't do *anything* useful these days, could you describe what exactly are you trying to get? An unique machine identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, at least not exactly.  HostID was usually a way to lock a piece of software to a node. Even in the later days of Solaris you could easily change the HostID, making it less locked to hardware.

You could use the network MAC, which should be globally unique. But these are easily cloned

You can also try the [CPUID](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx)

There have been similar questions answered on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99880/generating-a-unique-machine-id)

Comment: These days in Linux/glibc the hostid is just read from `/etc/hostid` if exists.

Answer (score 0):

The registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography` has a value `MachineGuid` containing a randomly-generated GUID. This is static, but easily changeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) which comes with the hostid command.